# How to filter rows in a dataframe in R in a summation and apply grouping?

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

I have the following Rscript.

```
library(data.table)

  # input here is a data frame, and note it has columns col1, col2, id, date 
  output <- input[,j=list(
      col1 = sum(col1),
      col2 = sum(col2),
          by=date]
```

I don't know any R, but from my understanding, this code is accumulating over each column and grouping by `date` column.

I want to modify the computation for `col2` to not include the rows with an `id` that's in  `do_not_include_ids`.

So I tried to do the following:

```
rows_filtered <- !(input$id %in% do_not_include_ids)
output <- input[,j=list(
      col1 = sum(col1),
      col2 = sum(col2[rows_filtered]),
          by=date]
```

However, this seems to just sum over all of `col2[rows_filtered]` and then assigns this value to all the dates, so it seems the grouping is not working here.

Answer (score 2):

In your code `rows_filtered` does not respect the grouping by `date`.
We have to apply the filter within each group. In this case we use inline filtering. If you need to apply the filter to multiple columns or if your filtering logic is more complex then move the filtering logic to  `.SD` (Subset of Data) and `.SDcols` in data.table.

```
library(data.table)

input <- structure(list(col1 = c(10, 20, 15, 10, 5, 30), col2 = c(5, 10, 
5, 20, 25, 10), id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1), date = structure(c(18628, 
18628, 18629, 18629, 18629, 18630), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

do_not_include_ids <- c(1, 5)

output <- input[, .(
  col1_sum = sum(col1),
  col2_sum = sum(col2[!id %in% do_not_include_ids])
), by = date]
output

         date col1_sum col2_sum
1: 2021-01-01       30       10
2: 2021-01-02       30       25
3: 2021-01-03       30        0
```

Comment: Is `.SD` used in your code? Apologies if I missed it but I don't think I see it

Comment: No `.SD` is not used as you can see. Here we simply do the filtering inline. The use of `.SD` and `.SDcols` is appropriate if you need to apply the filter to multiple columns or if your filtering logic is more complex. Please see my update!

Comment: ahh so using `sum(col2[rows_filtered])` (in my code) is different than using `sum(col2[!id %in% do_not_include_ids])` (in your code)

Comment: Seems that's indeed the case. So the example in the OP is just a minimal example. In reality, I have to do the filtering over numerous columns. I do not want to write out  `!id %in% do_not_include_ids` for each column. Is there a way to store it and index by it like how I did previously?

Comment: @roulette01, it is simple enough to do something like `input[, lapply(.SD, function(z) sum(z[!z %in% do_not_include_ids])), .SDcols = c("col1", "col2"), by = date]` to apply the logic to all of the `col*` columns identically; if you have some columns that require the conditional summing and others that do not, then `input[, c(list(col1 = sum(col1)), lapply(.SD, function(z) sum(z[!z %in% do_not_include_ids]))), .SDcols = c("col2", "col3", "col4")), by = date]` is one pattern to follow. Hope this helps; if not, then please edit your question to make the sample data more representative.